# Can Context Switching happens between ISRs?

Tags: operating-system

I am still a new learner in this field and appreciate anyone who can give me some opinions.

Let me introduce the situation of my problem:
1.The keyboard interrupt occurs when Process A is executing. As far as I know, it doesn't matter if Process A was executing in user mode or kernel mode. The Interrupt Handler will be invoked to deal with the keyboard interrupt in kernel mode.
2.The Interrupt Handler will save the state of Process A in its kernel stack and executes the ISR corresponding to the keyboard interrupt(still using the kernel stack of Process A).
3.During the execution of the keyboard ISR, the clock interrupt occurs. Then the interrupts will be nested.
4.The Interrupt Handler will save the state of the keyboard ISR in the kernel stack of Process A and executes the ISR corresponding to the clock interrupt(still using the kernel stack of Process A).
5.The clock ISR updates the system time and finishes. But os finds out the time slice of Process A has been used up.

Question:
1.What will the os do next?
Will the os schedule another process first Or will the os finish the keyboard ISR first? I prefer the former because the state of the interrupted keyboard ISR is saved in the kernel stack of Process A. It can be restored when Process A is selected to run after some time. Am I right?
2.Is there any difference in interrupt handling between common os(like Linux) and real time os?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no single answer to this question. The exact behavior depends on the interrupt controller implementation, if the OS supports Symmetric multi processing(SMP) and the specific scheduler.

The interrupt controller implementation is important because some processors do not support nested ISRs while some do. CPUs that do not supported nested interrupts are going to return to kernel operation after servicing an interrupt. If multiple interrupts are triggered in a narrow time window so servicing overlaps, typically the CPU will enter kernel mode very briefly and then return back to an interrupt context to handle the next interrupt. If nested interrupts are supported then the typical behavior is for the CPU to stay in the interrupt context until the "stack" of interrupts is serviced before returning to a kernel context.

The OS supporting SMP is also very important to the exact behavior of interrupt handling. When SMP is supported, it possible, and probably very likely, that the another core may be scheduled to handle the kernel and subsequent user space workload to handle what ever the interrupt trigged. Suppose the ISR served a Ethernet port on core 1, upon completion of the ISR, core 1 could service another interrupt, while core 2 wakes up and runs the user process waiting on the network traffic from the ethernet port.

To add a final wrinkle of complexity, interrupts can typically be routed to different CPUs, the exact way dependent on the interrupt controller implementation. This is done to minimize interrupt latency by keeping all the interrupts from pilling up on one CPU waiting for the sequential handling.

Finally, typical scheduler implementations don't track the ISR servicing time when calculating time slices for a given thread. As for the difference in handling between a traditional fair scheduler or an RTOS, there generally are not significant differences. Ultimately its the interrupt controller hardware that dictates the order interrupts are handled in, not the software's thread scheduler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I learned a lot. Thanks!